# is $||T|| ≤1$ imply $I-T$ is positive operator and hence imply $I-T$ is self adjoint .

Tags: functional-analysis

I deduced that in a hilbert space over complex feild $||T|| ≤1$ imply $ I-T$ is positive operator .

assume $||T|| ≤1$ then-

$( [I-T]x,x)=( x-Tx,x) = (x,x)-(Tx,x)=||x||^2-(Tx,x)$

now using Cauchy-Swartz inequality $|(Tx,x)|\le||Tx||.||x||\le||T||.||x||.||x||\le||x||^2$

i.e $I-T$ is positive operator.

and this imply I-T is self adjoint. but i think this is not true, for example in ℓ2 ,for left shift operator $||T||=1$ but $I-T$ is not self adjoint.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Simply having $\lVert T\rVert \le 1$ does not guarantee self-adjointness, so does not guarantee positivity. Specifically, your argument shows that the absolute value of $((I - T)x, x)$ is at least 0, but does not show that  it is real.

Comment: thank you sir..I got my mistake that $(Tx,x)$ may not be real. if this is real then result will be true

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- The definition I have of $S$ positive operator in a Hilbert space $H$ is
$$(Sx,x)\ge 0 \text{ for all } x\in H$$ This definition has implicit that $(Sx,x)$ is real because the set $\mathbb C$ of complex numbers is not ordered (*you have not, for example,  a sense  for $5+7i\ge 0$*). It follows that the conjugate of $(Sx,x)$ is equal to $(x,Sx)=(Sx,x)$. Thus $S$ is self adjoint.

(*Actually that $(Sx,x)$ is real for all $x$ is a well known equivalent definition of self adjointness in Hilbert spaces*).